# Could not connect to Uipath Orchestrator from Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I am trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline for Uipath Project Using Azure DevOps Pipelines following the the steps below

https://www.uipath.com/community-blog/tutorials/how-to-implement-cicd-pipeline-using-azure-devops-pipelines

but i am getting an error like this.

```
Please make sure that the provided URL (https://cloud.uipath.com/) is correct, available from your build agent, and not blocked by a firewall.
If the Orchestrator is using a self-signed SSL certificate, make sure that the build agent trusts it. Ensure that all the steps at https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/self-signed-certificates were correctly followed when creating the certificate.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the doc mentioned, and can reproduce the same error with `External Application` type service connection:

[image]

I resolve the error by changing to use `Token Based Authentication` service connection.
steps as below:

1. Go 'preference' below -> Privacy&security -> check the API access for the target domain.
   [image]
2. Copy the user key, it will be used as token value in service connection.

[image]

3. Go to devops, create `Token Based Authentication` service connection.
   [image]

The pipeline works:

[image]

You can also refer to the [link](https://forum.uipath.com/t/azure-pipeline-and-orchestrator-connection-issue/402527/9) for your reference.

[image]